# Customer balance sheet in seperate table

Tags: database-design

Wanted to ask if it's an acceptable design practice to have a separate table for customer balance. I don't need to see a full balance sheet like you would have on a bank account balance sheet, where there you have all the transactions AND the balance. I just need to record each time the client balance changes, so the **Client_balance_sheet** table would get a new record on each bill or transaction, and his current balance would get updated, and the table would only have a relationship with the **Clients** table.

My logic is that to do this programmatically, I would have to query ALL client's Orders AND Transactions to get his balance and that would take longer as the client gets more and more orders and transactions recorded in the database.

So the **Client_balance_sheet** table would get a new record each time the client is billed or makes a payment.

Another thing I thought of is to give up on the dates of the balance and just calculate and record the current balance after each order or transaction, in a "balance" **field** in the **Clients** table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wary of storing derived data, it always seems to find a way to become inconsistent, unless you can get the DBMS to manage it for you. It's also doesn't necessarily increase performance - writes are slower than reads and incur locks and index updates. It may be prudent to just do the calculation on orders and transactions when required, and wait for it to slow down as your database gets populated.

If you decide to store balances, I would recommend looking at triggers to manage it.

As for storing the balance with a date: latest record queries for multiple clients at a time are a hassle and may end up slower than calculating it from the orders and transactions. Storing only the current balance will be easier to work with. You can still calculate it for any given date when required.

None of your ideas are wrong, but they incur additional complexity and effort. I would wait until it the situation demands it before doing any of these.

Comment: The thing is that whenever I choose a client in the main window of the software, I want the total balance to be displayed. I am constantly going from client to client and would think that calculating every transaction of a client each time I select a client would be over-kill. But if you think that read speed is fast enough to handle this, that would be ok.